# Where is mail.php when installing the Zend Framework for Zend Mail?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

To start out, this is my first post here. I am trying to do a simple install of the Zend Mail, for the Zend Framework. All instructions point to including the **Mail.php** file, from the library folder. 
include(Zend/Mail.php)
However, I downloaded the Zend package as a tar, ZF 2.4.9, and it does not include a mail.php in the library folder. 
Any hints?

Comment: What is the error message that you got that you think would need you to manually include mail.php?

Comment: It is code that was given to us by the professor. In the code it shows includes Zend/mail.php. so when we run it obviously it says it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are following instructions for ZF1, but you have downloaded ZF2. Take a look at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html instead.

Note that ZF2 should be installed with Composer rather than downloaded as an archive.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will look into that. I simply downloaded the last archive before composer was necessary.